# Assigning specific colors to specific cases in ridgeline plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

Recently this community helped me tremendously with getting Ridgeline plots to work with my data.
Now I am struggling with coloring them according to my needs.
Basically what I want is plotting my cases in different orders but they should keep a specific color so observations remain recognizable even when plotted in a different order. So far I failed with applying the available solutions to my requirements.

Let us take for example this data, where we have a name, a mean and an SD:

```
caseName    caseMean    caseSD
Svansdottir 2006    -0.0646 0.4032398
Guétin 2009 -0.4649 0.3995663
Raglio 2010a    -0.2145 0.2814031
```

Let's first sort them by caseMean:

```
df$caseName <- factor(df$caseName, levels = df$caseName[order(df$caseMean)])
```

and plot it with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse); library(ggridges)
n = 100
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(low  = caseMean - 3 * caseSD, high = caseMean + 3 * caseSD) %>%
  uncount(n, .id = "row") %>%
  mutate(x    = (1 - row/n) * low + row/n * high, 
         norm = dnorm(x, caseMean, caseSD))
ggplot(df3, aes(x, caseName, height = norm, fill=caseName)) +
  geom_ridgeline(scale = 2,alpha=0.75) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

we get this: [image: sorted by caseMean]

Now we reverse the order

```
df$caseName <- factor(df$caseName, levels = df$caseName[order(-df$caseMean)])
```

and plot again with the code above we see that the plots have switched color: [image: cases in reverse order]

How can I make sure that the same cases have always the same colors no matter the order I put them in?

I would like to have code that doesn't require me to to "hard-wire" colors to a specific case name. I want to be able to do this to ridgeline plots with 20, 30, or more observations. The fact that I picked the viridis color palette doesn't matter. I am happy with any solution (like with heat.colors or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

If your new factor is just reversing the order of the previous one, you could use the argument `direction` in `scale_fill_viridis_d()`.

For more complicated cases (i.e. re-leveling a factor), a possibility is to add the colour manually, possibly in your orginal data-frame, and to feed it with `scale_fill_manual()`

#### simple case: reversing order of factor

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(name = letters[3:1], value = c(3,1,2))

pl_1 <- ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name), data=df)+
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()

pl_1
```

[image]

```r
pl_1 %+% mutate(df, name = factor(name, levels = c("c", "b", "a"))) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction=-1)
#> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill',
#> which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

#### More complicated case

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

df_new <- tibble(name = letters[3:1], value = c(3,1,2),
                     col = rev(viridis(3))) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("c", "b", "a"))) %>% 
  arrange(name)

df_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=df_new$col)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your effort and your reply! I am afraid I don't fully understand what is going on there. When I sort the observations by value like this:

df_new$name <- factor(df_new$name, levels = df_new$name[order(df_new$value)])

and plot it again the colors remain in the same order as before. The color codes in the variable col are correct, though.